# How to put multiple shapes on a single figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am relatively new to python, what i am trying to do here is put a number of the same shape on a single figure, have i not included something inside or outside the for or while loop?

I typed in plt.show() but it does not show anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OY4N.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *entirely* sure what the intended output is, and I assume part of the code is cut off, but I can point out a few problems with your snippet of code.

First, `for x in range(0,5)` will yield `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` as values for `x`. This means that `x > 5` can never be true, and the body of the `while`-loop will never be reached!

I've also noticed that you have given `y == y + 0.1` as both the x- and y-coordinate. In Python, `==` is the equality operator, so it will check if `y` and `y + 0.1` are equal and return either `True` or `False`. Of course, `y` and `y + 0.1` are never equal, so this will always yield `False` as your coordinate. I assume you want to increase `y` by `0.1` and then yield this new value. This can be done by using `y := y + 0.1` instead. Here, the 'walrus operator' `:=` is specifically meant to assign a value to a variable and simultaneously return this value to use.

Your way of adding a rectangle using `Rectangle` and `add_patch` should work perfectly fine, as can be seen using the following minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
rectangle = plt.Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.1, 0.1, fc='blue', ec='red')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

This will show us our rectangle:
[image: rectangle].

Hopefully this will help you fix your code, and if you run into more problems, let me know :).

Comment: Hi, sorry i should have been a bit more precise, the intended output should be more than one  box in the same figure, but without repeatedly creating many objects(by this i mean the shapes on the figure, i have just started OOP, so please let me know if am wrong). I changed it to x>=5, however it does not show the figure, is that to do with the while or for loop?. Also is the walrus operator the same as y += 0.1?. How did you make the snippets of code in your explanation look like actual code. Thank you very much for the response btw

Comment: @Abdurahman Hi, sorry it took a while to respond. As far as I know, the `Rectangle` objects (and any similar ones) can only be used once, so you'd have to make multiple object either way. I don't like it either, but there's probably a reason on their end to do it that way. I'm not sure why it still doesn't show, but that's because I can't see your full code. The walrus operator here does the same as `y += 0.1` (more precisely, `y = y + 0.1``), but while also returning the value of `y`. Code can be formatted by wrapping it in backticks (on the `~` key). You can find it in the formatting help.